# Setup PPTP to access home network transparently

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, raspberry-pi, pptp

I have **Raspberry Pi** box connected to home WiFi-router and running `pptpd`.  The local addresses is `192.168.1.32` (eth0) and `192.168.2.1` (ppp0) and local name `raspberry.local`.

I have **iMac** connected to the same router with local IP  `192.168.1.27` and local name `imac.local`

I have **Macbook** somewhere in the Internet connected to Raspberry’s PPTP with `192.168.2.10` on ppp0

This picture shows more clearly.

[image]

### pptpd configuration

PPTP on Raspberry was installed  from [this simple script](https://github.com/viljoviitanen/setup-simple-pptp-vpn).

**/etc/pptpd.conf**

```
option /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
logwtmp
localip 192.168.2.1
remoteip 192.168.2.10-100
```

**/etc/ppp/options.pptpd**

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
lock
nobsdcomp 
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
```

**/etc/rc.local**

```
…
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT  --protocol 47 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1356
…
```

### Curent connectivity

Macbook

- can connect to home PPTP and connect to Internet through the home router
- can connect to iMac and Raspberry via local IPs `192.168.1.27` and `192.168.1.32`
- can *NOT* resolve `raspberry.local` and `imac.local`

Raspberry

- can connect to iMac and Macbook via local IPs `192.168.1.27`  and `192.168.2.10`
- can resolve `imac.local`
- can *NOT* resolve `macbook.local`

iMac

- can connect to Raspberry via local IP `192.168.1.32`
- can resolve `raspberry.local`
- can *NOT* connect to Macbook via local IP `192.168.2.10` (**upd:** Solved by adding static route to the router)
- can *NOT* resolve `macbook.local`

### The goal

The goal is to connect and resolve local names from any to any. But I have no idea how to configure this: iptables, avahi, netatalk or somewhere else?

Comment: The Multicast DNS uses multicast addresses that are not routable.  IE Bonjour/Avahi is not going to work across a router.  You are going to need to use another name resolution protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The use of an ip address in the iptable is ok. However, one can also use a statement that does not involve an IP address but a referance to the eth0 interface. It does remove a variable from the process:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Note:: to check that the iptables is active after reboot:
iptables -t nat -L

The script to enable iptables is started from the /etc/network/interfaces file that may be a bit different. the line has manual and not dhcp at the time of this writing. Just put the script name in after the line anyway:
iface eth0 inet manual

Also, the local ip_address is optional in openvpn.conf. Without the definition, OpenVPN will listen on all interfaces. Again, removing a variable from the process.

For further variable reduction, ie obtaining an openvpn.conf that works on any Raspberry without reference to the IP's used on the Raspberry, one can also use the Google DNS server and not push a route for the localnetwork.
Note that removing the route for the localnetwork means no access to the local network but allows access to the Internet with start up tests: add the route / local [express DNS](http://www.expressvpnreviewz.com/) latter when one is more sure of the setup.